# The csv file imported to neo4j, there are multiple fields in each line, how can I import these fields separately?

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

[this is example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPNmb.png)

[image]

For example, there are 2 in the Shareholder field. I want to import both into the neo4j database. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS row
WITH row
SKIP 1
UNWIND row AS name
MERGE (s:Person {name: name})
```

The `SKIP 1` clause is there to ignore the header row, since it is not useful (since there are actually 2 data columns in your CSV file, but you only have a single header). Since each row is an array of comma-delimited names, the `UNWIND` clause separates the names. And the `MERGE` clause is used instead of `CREATE` as a precaution to prevent duplicates.

Comment: thanks,but is Useless,and then I use the software to separate the lines and import them.